# Does voice stress analysis work for Lie Detection?

Tags: software, lie-detection, voice

There seem to be many Voice Stress analysis software available.

Does vocie stress analysis work for lie detection?

How reliable is it?

The first one I found was a Skype plugin

http://kishkish-lie-detector.en.uptodown.com/windows

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jBfUsxq648

> KishKish Lie Detector analyzes the stress level in the speaker’s voice and decides if they are lying or not.

There are other software claiming the same.